# jQuery submit event not fired when calling DOM submit method

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When I use the [DOM form submit method](http://www.w3.org/2003/01/dom2-javadoc/org/w3c/dom/html2/HTMLFormElement.html#submit__) to submit a form, the [jQuery submit event handler](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) isn't called, even though w3c says: "It performs the same action as a submit button."

I tried with jQuery 1.11.0 and 2.1.0.

```
<form id="form">
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit()">submit onClick</button>
</form>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/g0kxmdmw/6/ for a full example.

In both Firefox and Chrome, pressing enter in the text input, clicking "submit button" and "submit jquery" will all trigger the handler and cancel the form submit, while "submit `onClick`" and "submit js dom" don't trigger the handler, and will perform the submit (a `GET` request).

I expected that calling the submit method would show the same behaviour as clicking a submit button, but it doesn't. Is this a bug in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, calling the form's submit() method does not trigger the submit event so none of the event handlers will get triggered.

The submit event will be fired only when the user triggers it via a button click or any such actions.

[submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, onsubmit="return
>   false;") will not be triggered when invoking this method from
>   Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be
>   invoked by HTML user agents.