# Alternative to AJAX async: false option for form submit button click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a login form where we make an AJAX call to the server to perform a bit of validation before letting the login form continue submitting. The current code is outlined below:

```
(function ($) {
    var errorMessageHtml = "";
    function isUserValid(username) {
        if (username.length <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        var userIsValid = false;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/myAjaxCall?username=" + username
        }).success(function (validationResult) {
            userIsValid = validationResult.IsValid;
            errorMessageHtml = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }).fail(function () {
            errorMessageHtml = "Error contacting server. Please try again.";
        });

        return userIsValid;
    }

    var $usernameTextbox = $("#UserName");
    var $errorMessageLabel = $(".errorMessageContainer");

    $(".loginButton").on("click", function (e) {
        $errorMessageLabel.hide();
        if (isUserValid($usernameTextbox.val())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $errorMessageLabel.show();
            $errorMessageLabel.html(errorMessageHtml);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I know that `async: false` is something that shouldn't be used since it's going out of style. My question is: What's the alternative. My click event handler needs to return true or false, meaning it has to wait for the ajax call to complete. If `async: false` is no longer an option, then the `isUserValid` method is going to return immediately without properly setting the `userIsValid` bool.

Now I can inline the ajax method call straight into the click event handler that's called on `$(".loginButton")`, but the same problem presents itself: It needs to either return true, or prevent default (i.e. prevent login) and return false depending on the result of the ajax call. Is there a way I can force the click event handler to wait for the result of the ajax call before returning, without using `async: false`? I understand there's a jQuery `when()` method, but I don't know if I can use that in this situation.

Comment: perhaps add one of the two in a function an call it on success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing, a `form` can be submited without clicking on respective submit button. So bind instead `submit` event to the `form`. Now depending ajax request result, you can submit the `form`, using e.g:

```
(function ($) {
    var errorMessageHtml = "";
    function isUserValid(username) {
        $errorMessageLabel.hide();
        if (username.length <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        var userIsValid = false;
        // return the promise from ajax method
        return $.ajax({            
            url: "/myAjaxCall?username=" + username
        }).success(function (validationResult) {
            userIsValid = validationResult.IsValid;
            errorMessageHtml = validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }).fail(function () {
            errorMessageHtml = "Error contacting server. Please try again.";
        });
    }

    var $usernameTextbox = $("#UserName");
    var $errorMessageLabel = $(".errorMessageContainer");
    // "form:has(.loginButton)" or whatever more relevant selector
    $("form:has(.loginButton)").on("submit", function (e) {
        $errorMessageLabel.hide();
        isUserValid($usernameTextbox.val())).always(function(validationResult ){
            if(validationResult && validationResult.IsValid) {
                this.submit();
            } else {
                $errorMessageLabel.html(errorMessageHtml).show();
            }
        }.bind(this));            

        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There's an infinite loop, no ? (triggering submit event in a submit listener ?)

Comment: @Magus No because here we are calling `submit()` DOM node method, not firing jq submit handler

Comment: @Magus [Here's a relevant Q/A on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344988/jquery-submit-event-not-fired-when-calling-dom-submit-method).  Nice answer btw, +1.

Comment: @A.Wolff the `validationResult` object wouldn't be available to the `always` method, would it? That gets returned from the AJAX call and is available on `success` but in the `fail` case the object doesn't exist.

Comment: @JamesThorpe It says `In general, it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.`, i'm not sure i'll rely on that. But it is off topic. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Scott missed this part (code not tested). See updated answer

Comment: @Magus You can rely on it on all browsers AFAIK

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks for the update. So the `always` method can conditionally receive the object that's normally returned to the `success` method (or `done` I suppose), but otherwise gets null (when failure occurs)? If so that's pretty cool.

Comment: For completion, the relevant parts of the spec are [the `submit` function definition here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) which eventually leads on to [step 5 here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-form-submit) - ie because the `submit` function sets the flag, the event isn't raised.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. I think I'm going to stick with the global (between the two methods) variables, creating a `userIsValid` alongside the existing `errorMessageHtml`, since doing the various checks against the maybe-exists-maybe-exception-object `validationResult` in `always` is proving cumbersome. Still, you got me to a working solution!

Comment: @Scott you can handle it using `isUserValid($usernameTextbox.val())).done(function()/*success*/}).fail(function(){/*error*/});` instead of setting respective ajax option callbacks

Comment: @A.Wolff good point. Changing to use that instead. And I think I know the answer to this, but `bind(this)` is just updating the `this` context so that when we call `this.submit()` within `always`, `this` is set to the form instead of the usual `this` within `always`? (`this` semantics in JS are always fun!)

Comment: @Scott Ya, that's exactly here the purpose of it. Relevant DOC is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

[A. Wolff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32949314/100534) is the answer I accepted, but I wanted to share my final code solution based off their input as well as the various comments made back and forth.

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var $usernameTextbox = $("#UserName");
    var $passwordTextbox = $("#Password");
    var $errorMessageLabel = $(".errorMessageContainer");

    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
        $errorMessageLabel.hide();
        var username = $usernameTextbox.val();
        if (username.length <= 0 || $passwordTextbox.val().length <= 0) {
            return; // Server posts back with "username/password required" so we don't handle it here.
        }

        $.get("/myAjaxCall?username=" + username).done(function (validationResult) {
            if (validationResult.IsValid) {
                this.submit();
            } else {
                $errorMessageLabel.html(validationResult.ErrorMessage).show();
            }
        }.bind(this)).fail(function() {
            $errorMessageLabel.html("Error contacting server. Please try again.").show();
        });            

        e.preventDefault();
    });
})(jQuery);
```